# Can 'locals' be used with 'collection' when rendering partials in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Everything works okay when I try to render a partial like this:

```
= render :partial => "/shared/enquiry/car_type", :collection => @enquiry.available_car_types
```

However, if I also want to pass a variable (in this case 'path', because I'm sharing this partial across two forms), the path is not available to me:

```
= render :partial => "/shared/enquiry/car_type", :collection => @enquiry.available_car_types, :locals => {:path => customers_enquiry_path}
```

I've tried moving things around, but nothing appears to work, leading me to believe one cannot use locals with collections. Any help would be appreciated.

Gav

Comment: Can you provide more details of how "nothing appears to work"?

Answer (score -10, accepted):

No you can't use them together. Ref [this](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html)

I think you have to do something like following

```
  <% for ad in @enquiry.available_car_types %>
    <%= render :partial => "/shared/enquiry/car_type", :locals =>{ :ad => ad, :path =>customers_enquiry_path } %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Where in the reference does it say you can't use them together?  According to the current rails guide, using :locals and :collection is allowed

Comment: As other comments have said this appears to be allowed as stated in the Rails Guide.

Comment: I'll reenforce that this is possible to use them both together. I've used this approach many times.

Answer (score 35):

Like the guides said,
specify the `:as` option in the call to the partial

[image]

Comment: @gav Can you please mark this answer as the correct solution please?

Comment: url: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#local-variables

Answer (score 20):

For Rails 4.x, if you pass the collection directly to render (which you must do if you want to use automatic partial selection for a heterogeneous collection), the next parameter is interpreted as a hash of locals.

Try the following:

```
= render @enquiry.available_car_types, :path => customers_enquiry_path
```

Answer (score 12):

What version are you using? Using my 2.3.5 I'm able to do just that:

```
render :partial => "/site_articles/article", :collection => @site_articles, :locals => { :footer => true }
```

, which you can find explained in other places, such as 3.4.6 of [this](http://guides.rails.info/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Answer (score 2):

@Gav, you are running into two issues.

1. `render` ignores the `locals` option when passing the collection as the first parameter. You need to instead specify the `partial` and `collection` parameter options, as you have in your second example.
2. `path` likely falls into the realm of a reserved word. Try using something else.